# Cannot install FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've followed [this Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2c522246-8450-408d-b907-197dfa0fdbb6.mspx?mfr=true) to install FrontPage Server Extensions 2002 on Windows Server 2003:

> To install and enable FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions
>
> 1. From the Start menu, click Control Panel.
> 2. Double-click Add or Remove Programs.
> 3. Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
> 4. In the Windows Components Wizard, double-click Application Server, double-click Internet Information Services, and then select the
>      FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions check box.
> 5. Click OK twice, click Next, and then click Finish.

However on step 4, "FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions" does not show up in the list in the IIS details window.  How do I get FPSE 2002 installed on my server?

From what I can understand it's supposed to be there and I just have to enable it, but that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this MS link.

[ASP/FrontPage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832095)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I read in there "On a 64-bit edition, there is no option for FrontPage Server Extensions in Add/Remove Components.", they provide an article on how to install FPSE via command line as a solution.